# Context menu in action bar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextmenu

Please help me. I use the context menu in Action Bar (CAB). Listing menu has the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_cxtmenu"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="edit"/>
    <item/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit_cxtmenu"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="edit"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete_cxtmenu"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="delete"/>
</menu>
```

So the menu should consist of three items. Each item has a parameter `android:showAsAction="always"` 
In the end, I had to get three icons on the panel ActionBar. But in reality, I have two icons together into a button overflowbutton. How to fix it? I can not find the answer to this problem.
Theme my app

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Comment: If your icons dont enter in your action bar, they will automatically appear in your overflown menu, try to reduce  or remove your activity title, but I am not sure if that will work. Try putting your device in landscape mode, do your items appear separatedly?

Comment: Yes, in any orientation so grouped. 
Landscape    http://prntscr.com/7ys6jo
portrait    http://prntscr.com/7ys6rh

Comment: Is it normal that you have an empty item? If you are using AppCompat, you need to use `app:showAsAction` instead of `android:showAsAction`, else it will be ignored.

Comment: Yes, I have already corrected. Yes, I have already corrected. But the action bar also has a overflowbutton with empty menu. How do I remove the button is now?.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_cxtmenu"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="edit"/>
    <item/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit_cxtmenu"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="edit"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete_cxtmenu"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="delete"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Now I got the picture  http://prntscr.com/7ysa5t How can I remove overflowbutton?

Comment: have you added overflowbutton item in your Menu xml file?

Comment: Yes. The action bar has overflowmenu. But in the markup CAB not have overflowbutton. How can I make so that the action bar had a button but  it was not in cab

Comment: Try to remove android:orderInCategory tag.

Comment: If I make two items in the XML menu, then everything is fine. As the I want to, without buttons

Comment: which android:targetSdkVersion you have used?

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="21"
I test on my phone with 4.4.4

Comment: I don't understand you have added only three menu item in your xml file. this only happens if there is no enough room for menu items so overflow menu is showed

Comment: I also do not understand. All day today I am suffering.

Comment: If the code to add menu items, I just checked it all okay.
http://prntscr.com/7ysvfv
http://prntscr.com/7ysw5s
Magic ... But it is necessary to do in XML. It seems so correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

For this:

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

Also you couldn´t have enought room. Try to remove your title or do it small.

Comment: Now I got the picture prntscr.com/7ysa5t How can I remove overflowbutton?

Comment: Try using ifRoom. With this you will have overflow only if you haven`t room...and this is good.